# Providing a title for a MUI X Data Grid

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-x-data-grid, mui-x

I'm learning how to use the [MUI X Data Grid](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/) React Component (MIT licensed version).

Is it possible to add a title to a Data Grid? Just some simple centered text above the column headers but below the Data Grid border would be great, though having custom components in a title would be ideal.

Is there a built in way to do this?

**edit**: Here is an example of what I'm trying to do. In this screenshot, I did it by wrapping the DataGrid in a div and giving that div a border, and removing the DataGrid border.

[image]

Is there some way to do this natively with the Data Grid interface?

Answer (score 2):

Update for MUI 5.x:

The prop has changed to `slots` which allows overriding many parts of the table. The toolbar is specified as

```
  slots={{
    toolbar: DataGridTitle
  }}
```

See https://mui.com/x/api/data-grid/data-grid/

Answer (score 0):

Solved! When constructing the Data Grid, you can use the `components` prop, which accepts a `ToolBar` component.

```
<DataGrid
    {...}
    components={{Toolbar: DataGridTitle}}
/>
```

Where `DataGridTitle` is your own component that can have a title in it. In this case, I'm using:

```
function DataGridTitle() {
        return(
            <Box style={{width: "100%", display: "flex", justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center"}}>
                <Typography variant="h5">Users</Typography>
            </Box>
        )
    }
```

And it works perfectly:

[image]